# Save complex page state with jQuery cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies, page-state

I have a page with a custom treeview. When a node is expanded, its child nodes are loaded via jQuery Ajax calls.

Now, I would like to save the current state of the treeview so that when the user leaves and returns to the page, the previously expanded treeview stay expanded.

In similar situations, I have saved data like search queries, results or form data in a cookie, using this jQuery plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

So far, I can see two options:

1. Save the expanded nodes ID's and reload the treeview from scratch, but:

   - potentially a lot of Ajax calls,
   - difficult to make the calls in the right order (i.e. don't load the children before the parent is there),
   - waiting time for the calls to finish
2. Save the entire element containing the treeview into a cookie, but:

   - may be a lot of data
   - may have difficulties with attaching the right jQuery events to the node elements when inserting the treeview HTML into the DOM on load.

Thank you in advance for any ideas!

Chris

Comment: This should be probably handled server side as well - ie read the state of the cookie server side to see if the menu is open and then load the data and show it server side on first load if it is, that way you only need to remember the open state.  You can then use your ajax calls for any closed nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past I used the cookie approach. But the data was too big for the cookie header, so I send the state to the server with ajax and stored it there. Doing this you can restore the state while rendering the tree.